# Proof of this theorem about non-elementary integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

[image]

Can someone find a proof or show it here? 
I found the theorem here:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301565929_Indefinite_Nonintegrable_Functions_or_Nonelementary_Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $F(x) = \int f(x)dx$ is elementary. Moreover $f^{-1}(x)$ is also elementary.

Use the substitution $u = f^{-1}(x)$ and integration by parts in $G(x) = \int f^{-1}(x)dx$ to obtain $\int uf'(u)du = uf(u)-F(u)$.

Substituting back $u = f^{-1}(x)$ we find $G(x) = xf^{-1}(x) - F(f^{-1}(x))$ is elementary.

A symmetric argument would show the converse assuming $f(x)$ is elementary instead.

Comment: The same proof can be applied to show that is $f$ has no elementary primitive, than $f^{-1}$ also has no elementary primitive?