# Prove that if $\int f(x) dx$ is non elementary then $\int f^{-1}(x) dx$ is also non elementary

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I asked this question yesterday but I can't understand a few things.

[Proof of this theorem about non-elementary integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588305/proof-of-this-theorem-about-non-elementary-integrals)

Here I'm assuming $F(x) = \int f(x)\:dx$ is non elementary.

If you make $u = f^{-1}(x)$ then $du = (f^{-1}(x))' \:dx$. I understantd that $f'(u)=1$.
So, $\int (f^{-1}(x))\:dx $ = $\int \frac{u}{u'}f'(u)\:du $. If $u'$ is the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$.

How I get to this result $\int u f'(u) \:du$ ? And $F(u) = \int f(u)\:du$?

If somenone can make a way more detailed proof I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are inverses of each other.
2. Because they're inverses, $(f\circ g) = \text{identity}$. Hence by the chain rule, $(f\circ g)^\prime = 1 = (f^\prime \circ g)\cdot g^\prime$, so $(f^\prime \circ g) = \frac{1}{g^\prime}$.
3. Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ and $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt $ be antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$, respectively.
4. Using integration by substitution ("u-substitution"), we know that

   $$G(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt = \int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(x)} (g\circ f)(u) \cdot f^{\prime}(u) du$$

   but $f^{-1} = g$ and also $g\circ f= \text{identity}$, because $g$ and $f$ are inverses. Hence:

$$G(x) = \int_{g(0)}^{g(x)} u\cdot f^\prime(u)\,du$$

5. To evaluate this integral, let $h(u)=u$ be the identity function and consider the product rule: $(f\cdot h)^\prime = f^\prime \cdot h + f\cdot h^\prime$. If we integrate both sides from $a$ to $b$, we find:

$$[f\cdot h]_{a}^b = \int_{a}^b f^\prime\cdot h + \int_{a}^b f\cdot h^\prime$$

6. But of course $h^\prime = 1$. Hence we find a simplification:
   $$[f\cdot h]_{a}^b = \int_{a}^b f^\prime\cdot h + \int_{a}^b f$$
   or 
   $$\int_a^b f^\prime \cdot h = [f\cdot h]_a^b - [F(b)-F(a)]$$
7. Hence 
   $$G(x) = \int_{g(0)}^{g(x)} u\cdot f^\prime(u)\,du = [f\cdot h]_{g(0)}^{g(x)} - [F(g(x)) - F(g(0))]$$

   $$G(x) = g(x)\cdot f(g(x)) - g(0) \cdot f(g(0)) - F(g(x)) + F(g(0))$$

   $$G(x) = x g(x) - 0 - F(g(x)) + F(g(0))$$
   $$G(x) = xg(x) - F(g(x)) \;\;\;+\underbrace{F(g(0))}_{=const.}$$
8. Now we bring in our elementariness assumption: suppose $f$ and $g$ are elementary. If $F$ is elementary, then so are $x\cdot g(x)$, $(F\circ g)$, and so on. Hence $G$ is elementary.
9. We could have done this proof with the names $f$ and $g$ exchanged  (along with $F$ and $G$) . By switching the role of $f$ and $g$ in our proof, we get an exactly analogous result: if $G$ is elementary, then so is $F$.
10. Hence, assuming $f$ and $g$ are elementary, $F$ is elementary if and only if $G$ is.

Comment: If I define $F(x) = \int f(x) dx$, is wrong to say that $F(u)=\int f(u) du$? I though that the $dx$ sign cannot be changed to $du$.

Comment: Also, it's ok to change the u-substitution rule?

Comment: I mean the $du$ sign is on both side of the equality. Should't be a diferent variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain more?  1. The expression $F(x) = \int^x f$ means something like "F is an antiderivative of f". The "variable of integration" is a placeholder variable.  Because it's a placeholder, you can use any var name with no problem: $F(x)=\int_a^x f(y)dy = \int_a^x f(z)dz$.  2. There is only one integration by substitution rule. I haven't changed it, but I might be writing it in a way that looks different? Let me know how I can help.

Comment: The substitution "rule" that i saw is $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$. Here $dx$ is changed to $dt$. But when you used the $du$ is kept in both sides of the equation and the limit of integration is also different. Is this a different "rule"? I don't understand how $\int_0^x g(u)du=\int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(x)} g(f(u))f'(u)du$

Comment: Oh I see. It's the same rule: (1) Variable names. You can always change the *name* of an integration variable, as long as you keep the integration limits the same and keep variable names unique. So you can always convert $\int_a^b q(x)\,dx$ to $\int_a^b q(t)\,dt$. Same limits, different name. Similarly, you could rewrite $f(g(t))g^\prime(t)\,dt$ as  $f(g(u))g^\prime(u)\,du$ if you wanted. (2) Limits. My limits are the same; just put $a \equiv g(0)$ and $b\equiv g(x)$. Then  because $g=f^{-1}$, $f(a) = 0, f(b) = x$, $a=f^{-1}(0)$, $b=f^{-1}(x)$. Now our substitution rules match.

Comment: I though that $a$ and $b$ supposed to be constants, then $b$ was not allowed to be $f^{-1}(x)$. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Also i was trying to prove this theorem as stated is the title. If $\int f$ is non elementary then $\int f^{-1}$ is also non elementary. But if i tried to prove this theorem defining a definite integral such as $F(x)=\int_a^x f(x) dx$, wasn't this gonna be a problem? Because the definite integral is a real number, but I'm trying to prove that the indefinite integral is non elementary. So instead of assuming $F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)dx$ is non elementary I should write $F(x)=\int f(x) dx$ instead? Without limits on the integral

Comment: It's not a problem that I'm using an integral with definite limits: Maybe it would help to use a specific example.  Let $f(u) = 2(u-3)$. Then $F(x) = \int_0^x f(u)\,du = 2\left[u^2/2 -
 3u\right]_{u=0}^{u=x} = x^2 - 6x$. So actually, $F$ does not just yield a constant number; it's a real-valued function and it's meaningful to ask if it's elementary.  The reason F is not constant is that one of the limits is a variable.

Comment: A (real-valued) function is a rule for turning an input number into an output number.  The rule for a function like $F(x)=\int_0^x f(u)\,du$ is: "given a number $x$, plug that number in as the upper limit of integration. Now the resulting integral is a definite integral with constant limits. Evaluate it, getting an output number."  So you see, F really does define a function. And it's not a problem that the limits are variable, because given the arguments to the function, the limits can be treated as fixed constants.

Comment: I still don't get how you used the subtitution rule keeping the $du$ in both sides of the equation. I'm doing the substitution $t=f^{-1}(u)$, then $du=f'(t)dt$ to yeld $\int f^{-1}(u)du=\int t f'(t)dt$ which requires a change of variable. How did you make $\int f^{-1}(u)du = \int u f'(u)du$ ? I mean keeping the $du$ on both sides.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71212/discussion-between-user326210-and-anon).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reformulate the original answer with more detail. Be careful : we are assuming that $F(x)=\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x$ **is elementary**. Our goal is to prove that $G(x)=\int f^{-1}(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is also elementary.

Using a u-substitution $u=f^{-1}(x)$, we have $x=f(u)$ so $\mathrm{d}x=f'(u)\mathrm{d}u$ and

$$
G(x)=\int u f'(u) \mathrm{d}u.
$$

Alternatively, you can differentiate the expression $u=f^{-1}(x)$ (this is slightly more complicated). You get $\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{f'(u)}\mathrm{d}x$, which is obviously the same result.

Now we integrate by parts :

$$
\begin{align}
G(x)&=\int uf'(u)\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&= uf(u)-\int f(u) \,\mathrm{d}u \\
&=uf(u)-F(u) \\
&=xf^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x)),
\end{align}
$$

so $G$ is elementary.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if I assume $\int f(x)dx$ is non elementary, then $\int f^{-1}(x)dx$ is also non elementary? It's is the exactly same proof that you wrote, right?

Comment: We know $\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ elementary $\implies$ $\int f^{-1}(x)\mathrm{d}x$ elementary. By swapping $f$ and $f^{-1}$ (they have a symmetric role), in fact $\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ elementary $\iff$ $\int f^{-1}(x)\mathrm{d}x$ elementary